# Insertar un número en un vector ordenado

Tags: c

`Buenas`, quisiera obtener ayuda sobre cómo solucionar el código por tal de que me funcione.

El planteamiento es el siguiente:

Tengo que introducir la longitud que tendrá mi vector (pongamos que 5), después tengo que introducir el vector (pongamos que nuestro vector será "1 2 3 5 6"), y por último tengo que introducir un número en el vector (pongamos que quiero introducir el número "4", es decir, entre el 3 y el 5.

Por el momento tengo esto, pero cuando compilo me sale el típico error de "Violación del segmento".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define nmax 50

void llegir_vector (int vector [],int num);
void mostrar_vector (int vector [], int num);
void insertar_orden(int vector [], int *num, int num_introduit);


    void main () {

        int cont, n, num, i, opcion, res, num_element, num_introduit;   
        int vector[nmax];
        n = 1;

        while (n!=0) {
            printf ("\nSelecciona una opcio: \n");
            printf ("1.- Introduïr un vector:\n");
            printf ("2.- Mostra el vector per pantalla.\n");
            printf ("3.- Inserta un número al vector.\n");
            scanf ("%d", &n);

            switch (n) {

                case 1: 
                    system("clear");
                    printf("Introdueix la longitud del vector: ");
                    scanf ("%d", &num);

                    printf ("Introdueix el vector: ");
                    llegir_vector (vector, num);
                    break;

                case 2: 
                    system("clear");
                    mostrar_vector (vector, num);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    printf ("Escriu el número a introduir: ");
                            scanf ("%d", &num_introduit);
                    insertar_orden (vector, num, num_introduit);
                    break;

            }
        }    
    }


    // Función número 1.

    void llegir_vector (int vector [],int num) {
        int i;
            for (i = 0; i<num; i++) {
                scanf("%d", &vector[i]);

            }
    }


    // Función número 2.

    void mostrar_vector (int vector [],int num) {
        int i;
            for (i = 0; i<num; i++) {
                printf ("%d ", vector[i]);
            }
    }


    //Función número 3.

    int insertar_orden(int vector [], int *num, int num_introduit) {
        int i, j, pos_max;
        i = 0;
        while ((vector[i] < num) && (vector[i] <= num_introduit)){
            i ++;
        }
        pos_max = i;

        for (i = *num; i = pos_max; i--){
            vector[i] = vector[i-1];        
        }    
        pos_max = num_introduit;
        *num = *num + 1;
        }
```

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Hay algunos errores en tu programa, algunos sin importancia (variables que declaras y luego no usas), otros aparentemente despistes. Otros más importantes de concepto.

Muchos de los errores pueden ser detectados por el compilador si al compilar le das la opción `-Wall` (suponiendo que tu compilador sea `gcc`). Esto genera gran cantidad de *warnings* que permiten detectar los fallos siguientes:

1. Variables no utilizadas: `cont`, `i`, `opcion`, `res` y `num_element` en la función `main()`. `j` en la función `insertar_orden().
2. El tipo retornado por `main()` debería ser `int` en lugar de `void`.
3. La función `insertar_orden()` dice retornar `int`, pero en realidad no retorna nada. Cambia su tipo retornado por `void`, o retorna algo.
4. Cuando invocas a `insertar_orden()` el parámetro `num` debe ser pasado por referencia (es decir `&num`), ya que la función espera ahí un puntero al número de elementos (entiendo que usas el paso por puntero porque la función necesita modificar el valor de `num`, aunque también podrías hacer que retorne el nuevo valor).
5. En el `while` dentro de `insertar_orden()` debes usar `*num` en vez de `num`, para acceder al valor apuntado en lugar de al puntero.
6. En el `for` que hay justo después, la condición que has puesto para repetir el bucle es `i = pos_max`. Eso no es una condición, sino una asignación. Le das a la variable `i` el valor `pos_max`. Si ese valor es distinto de cero, la asignación tendrá un valor de verdad "verdadero" por lo que el bucle se ejecutará siempre. Entiendo que estás tratando de mover los últimos elementos del vector, por lo que la condición habría de ser `i > pos_max`.

Por último hay un error de concepto que el compilador ya no puede detectar, y es que una vez has "hecho sitio" en el vector para meter el dato, haces `pos_max = num_introduit`, cuando deberías hacer `vector[pos_max] = num_introduit`.

Aplicando estas correcciones el código quedaría:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define nmax 50

void llegir_vector (int vector [],int num);
void mostrar_vector (int vector [], int num);
void insertar_orden(int vector [], int *num, int num_introduit);


int main () {

    int n, num, num_introduit;
    int vector[nmax];
    n = 1;

    while (n!=0) {
        printf ("\nSelecciona una opcio: \n");
        printf ("1.- Introduïr un vector:\n");
        printf ("2.- Mostra el vector per pantalla.\n");
        printf ("3.- Inserta un número al vector.\n");
        scanf ("%d", &n);

        switch (n) {

            case 1:
                system("clear");
                printf("Introdueix la longitud del vector: ");
                scanf ("%d", &num);

                printf ("Introdueix el vector: ");
                llegir_vector (vector, num);
                break;

            case 2:
                system("clear");
                mostrar_vector (vector, num);
                break;

            case 3:
                printf ("Escriu el número a introduir: ");
                        scanf ("%d", &num_introduit);
                insertar_orden (vector, &num, num_introduit);
                break;

        }
    }
}


// Función número 1.

void llegir_vector (int vector [],int num) {
    int i;
        for (i = 0; i<num; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &vector[i]);

        }
}


// Función número 2.

void mostrar_vector (int vector [],int num) {
    int i;
        for (i = 0; i<num; i++) {
            printf ("%d ", vector[i]);
        }
}


//Función número 3.

void insertar_orden(int vector [], int *num, int num_introduit) {
    int i, pos_max;
    i = 0;
    while ((vector[i] < *num) && (vector[i] <= num_introduit)){
        i ++;
    }
    pos_max = i;

    for (i = *num; i > pos_max; i--){
        vector[i] = vector[i-1];
    }
    vector[pos_max] = num_introduit;
    *num = *num + 1;
}
```

### Actualización

**¡Advertencia!** No sé si tu planteamiento corresponde al enunciado del ejercicio. Me refiero en particular a que `vector[]` sea un array de tamaño prefijado. Otra forma (bastante más compleja, por lo que quizás no es lo que te piden) es que se trate de un array dinámico que pueda ir aumentando de tamaño cuando se requiera.

En tu código su tamaño es de 50 elementos (el valor de la constante `nmax`), por lo que deberíamos asegurarnos de que nunca se intentan introducir más elementos, es decir, que `num` nunca se hace mayor que `nmax`.

Estas comprobaciones deberías hacerlas cuando lees el valor de `num` solicitándolo al usuario, y después cada vez que insertes un nuevo elemento en el vector.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, abulafia, ya he posteado varias veces y me has respondido todas las veces súper bien.
¿Puedo hacerte unas preguntillas?
¿Cómo puedo ser buen programador? Es que por más que lo intento siempre cometo fallos y a veces como que no entiendo como se hacen las cosas y me frustro.
¿Algún consejillo?

Gracias, tío.

Comment: @AlexIglesias :-) Qué quieres que te diga... seguir programando, seguir equivocándose y lo más importante, aprender a leer bien los mensajes de error y los warnings del compilador :-) No, en serio, la experiencia es fundamental y esa sólo se obtiene trabajando. Vas por el buen camino, ánimo.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo.
¿Y si quisiera solo agregar un número a mi vector?¿Cómo se haría?
No puedo hacer un vector [num] (última posición) + num_introduit, he hecho algo así:


  `vector [num] = num_introduit;
  vector [num] + 1;`

Comment: La idea de meterlo en `vector[num]` es correcta, aunque deberías comprobar que `num` sea menor que `nmax` (mira la actualización que añadí a mi respuesta). Lo que en cambio está mal es lo de `vector[num]+1` ¿qué pretendes con eso? La expresión daría como resultado el último elemento introducido más uno, pero ese resultado no lo guardas (ni tampoco lo necesitas, no creo que sea eso lo que quieres hacer). Si lo que intentas es incrementar `num`, debes hacerlo como en la función `insertar_orden()`